# How to integrate the bottom navigators with drawer navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to integrate the bottom navigators with drawer navigators and how to show the bottom navigations for all drawer screens. I did not get the bottom navigations except home screen

```
const BottomNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  { 
     HomeStack,
     MoneyTransferStack,
      // ReportStack,
     BankAndFinanceStack,
     NotificationStack,
  })

const LeftNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: BottomNavigator },
   BankAndFinanceScreen: {
    screen: BankAndFinanceScreenDrawerStack,
      navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="BankAndFinanceScreenDrawerStack" title="Bank & Finance" />
        )
      })

    },
  ComplaintScreen: { 
    screen: ComplaintScreenStack,
     navigationOptions: navOpt => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} screen="ComplaintScreenStack" title="Complaints" />
        )
      })
  },
});

    const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: {screen: LeftNavigator},
    // Main: {screen: BottomNavigator},
   ForgetPasswordScreen: { screen: ForgetPasswordScreen },
   LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
   RegisterScreen: { screen: RegisterScreen },
   ComplaintForm: { screen: ComplaintForm },
});
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: wait sir i will post a code